# Displaying datagridview records depending on button selected

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm making a form in c# where the datagridveiw displays the records from the database depending on what floor is selected. same with this [image]

The problem is after I created my code, I always get an error: `ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control`.
Can anyone give me an idea on how to make it possible to display the database records depending on button selected.

Anyway, this is my code below.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=1234;Database=postgres;"))
            {
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM information WHERE college = 'cbaa' AND floor = '1'", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);

                            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 5;

                            dataGridView2.Columns[0].Name = "roomNum";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Room No.";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "roomNum";

                            dataGridView2.Columns[1].Name = "type";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Room Type";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "type";

                            dataGridView2.Columns[2].Name = "sIllumination";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Standard Illumination";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "sIllumination";

                            dataGridView2.Columns[3].Name = "aIllumination";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Actual Illumination";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "aIllumination";

                            dataGridView2.Columns[4].Name = "difference";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Difference";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "difference";
                            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }    
        }
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=1234;Database=postgres;"))
            {
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM information WHERE college = 'cbaa' AND floor = '2'", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);

                            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 5;

                            dataGridView2.Columns[0].Name = "roomNum";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Room No.";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "roomNum";

                            dataGridView2.Columns[1].Name = "type";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Room Type";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "type";

                            dataGridView2.Columns[2].Name = "sIllumination";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Standard Illumination";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "sIllumination";

                            dataGridView2.Columns[3].Name = "aIllumination";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Actual Illumination";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "aIllumination";

                            dataGridView2.Columns[4].Name = "difference";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Difference";
                            dataGridView2.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "difference";
                            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }     
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting the DataSource to null before changing anything on the configuration of the DataGridView

Comment: @Steve. my records wont display if i set datasource to null

Comment: just remove the `dataGridView.ColumnCount = 5;` and generate the columns by yourself. As stated in the error message if you set the datasource you cannot set the columncount property.

Comment: I mean, after calling the Adapter Fill method, set the datasource to null, define your columns configuration and finally set the DataSource to the filled table